# Appending value in websql to a html textbox

Tags: jquery, html

Please can someone suggest a better way to do this, I want to append a user phone number in web sqldatabase to all textbox with id userphone in all other pages. Such that one the user registered the detail will be saved to web sqldatabase and later once needed it will be fetch from that websqldatabase. This the code indly review it please

```
addfrd(){
 if (!window.openDatabase) {
  alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
  return;
 }
 db.transaction(function(tran) {
   tran.executeSql('SELECT * FROM User', [],function(tx, result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
         var  a = result.rows.item(0)['phoneN'];
         document.getElementById("userphone").value=a;
        }

     },errorHandler);
 },errorHandler,nullHandler);


//$('#userphone').hide();
 $("#Addingfriend").click(function(){
  var frdname = $("#frdname").val();
  var userphone=$("#userphone").val();
 var frdphone=$("#frdphone").val();
 var dataString="frdname="+frdname+"&userphone="+userphone+"&frdphone="+frdphone+"&Addingfriend=";
 if($.trim(frdname).length>0 & $.trim(userphone).length>0 & $.trim(frdphone).length>0)
 {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url:"http://localhost/phonegap/addingfriend.php",
 data: dataString,
 crossDomain: true,
 cache: false,
 beforeSend: function(){ $("#Addingfriend").val('Connecting...');},
 success: function(data){
 if(data=="ok")
 {
 alert("you Have successfully added a friend");
 $("#Addingfriend").val('submit');
 AddValueToFrd();
 }
 else if(data=="Number Not Exist")
 {
 alert("Either your friend has not registered or You added yourself!");
 }
 }
 });
 }else{
 alert("Fill up all fields");
 }return false;
 });
 }


 //
 function AddValueToFrd() {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
    return;
    }
 db.transaction(function(trans) {
   trans.executeSql('INSERT INTO Friends(friendName,yourphn,friendPhone) VALUES (?,?,?)',[$('#frdname').val(), $('#userphone').val(),$('#frdphone').val()], nullHandler,errorHandler);
   });
alert('successfully added friend');
 return false;

}
```